# Execution time for database read in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the execution time for the below code

```
public Dataset<Row> loadData(SparkSession spark, String url, String query, String driver) {
        long startTime=System.nanoTime();
        Dataset<Row> readDataFrame= spark.read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", url)
                .option("dbtable", query)
                .option("driver", driver)
                .load();
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((endTime-startTime)/1000000);
        return readDataFrame;
    }
```

The above code gave me time as 20 ms. Now, I added an action below like

```
        long startTime=System.nanoTime();
        Dataset<Row> readDataFrame= spark.read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", url)
                .option("dbtable", query)
                .option("driver", driver)
                .load();
        long count=readDataFrame.count();
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((endTime-startTime)/1000000);
        return readDataFrame;
```

This code gave me 2000 ms as answer, which I suppose is correct.

Now, we already have an action later in the code and don't want to use persist since there could be memory issues. Is there a good way to find the time for this readDataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

That is a bad way to measure time taken for DataFrame operations.

Spark uses DAG for DataFrame operations. Unless you call upon any any action (eg. count) over that DataFrame, spark will continue to read into the DataFrame in the background. On the other hand, Transformations are lazy in nature i.e., they get executed only when called upon by an action. They are not executed immediately

If you have an action later in the code, it is best not to do a `.count()` now.

If you want to find the time taken for a DataFrame read to complete, it is advised you look into the Spark Job logs..

Comment: I agree with you. However, we want to store this read time in our database for monitoring purposes for every read. Hence, we wanted to have it from our code.

Comment: I'm not sure whether `sparkSession.time(df.collect())` would work with the Java API or not, but it sure does with the Scala API. Still it does the same you're trying above, hence wouldn't be of much use.

Comment: sparkSession.time() is there in Java but as you said, it does the same thing as I did and is giving the same results. Thanks for sharing the answer I will try to see if I can the API for my purpose.